# MongoDB - How to get last inserted record from a collection asynchronously

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous, mongodb-.net-driver

I found a way to do it synchronously but I am unable to do it asynchronously.

```cs
public async Task<UserModel> GetLastCreatedUser()
{
    return _users
        .Find(_ => true)
        .SortByDescending(u => u.DateCreated)
        .Limit(1);
}
```

The synchronous way gives me this error:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluent<BankingAppLibrary.Models.UserModel, BankingAppLibrary.Models.UserModel>' to 'BankingAppLibrary.Models.UserModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    BankingAppLibrary   C:\Users\lucas\source\repos\BankingApp\BankingAppLibrary\DataAccess\MongoUserData.cs    36  Active

Comment: check return types what you expect and what is returned by limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` at the end of `IFindFluent<UserModel, UserModel>` in order to return the value with `Task<UserModel>`.

And since your method is an asynchronous method, don't forget to add `await` as well.

Your code should be as below:

```cs
public async Task<UserModel> GetLastCreatedUser()
{
    return await _users
        .Find(_ => true)
        .SortByDescending(u => u.DateCreated)
        .Limit(1)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```